# Unable to locate Search bar element in Facebook with XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to locate the search bar and send input text to it with following code :

```
searchBar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_e_2"]/input[2]')

searchBar.send_keys("my-text-here")
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

but getting the following error :

```
File ".\get-quotes.py", line 46, in <module>
    searchBar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_e_2"]/input[2]')
  File "D:\ahmed-quotes\quote-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "D:\ahmed-quotes\quote-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "D:\ahmed-quotes\quote-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\ahmed-quotes\quote-env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="u_e_2"]/input[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

knowing that I copied the xpath from inspecting the element in the the Chrome browser.
What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Please post the HTML or site URL

Answer (score 1):

Facebook massively obfuscates its HTML to prevent you from doing this kind of thing. This includes generating random IDs, tags, and other attributes per-page.